# Beanshell catch(ex): Exception or Throwable?

Tags: java, exception, beanshell

What type of exception is caught by the beanshell catch(ex): Exception or Throwable?.

Example:

```
try {
    .... } catch (ex) {     }
```

Answer (score 5):

That loosely typed catch will catch everything "[Throwable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)."  That will include [Errors](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html), [Exceptions](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and their myriad children.  You can easily confirm this with:

```
try {
  new Throwable("Something Exceptional");
} catch (ex) {
  System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Throwable is a superclass (essentially) of Exception--anything that Exception catches will also be caught by Throwable.  In general usage they are the same, you rarely (if ever) see other throwable types.

Comment: True, but does not answer the question.  It could be rare but, what happens in the beanshell case if the code throws a Throwable that is not an Exception in the try block ?

Comment: Then the answer is, "Throwable" catches everything.  I thought that would be more clear from my answer.